# Frameworks and tools for UI testing of ExtJS based web apps

Tags: javascript, testing, extjs, automated-tests, ui-automation

I would like to test a web app that was drastically redesigned to use ExtJS to drive its UI.

I have done some online searching but couldn't find any recommendation for a good framework to handle it properly.

Up till now we have been using WatiN to create tests.

Note that we do not own the web app code.

What are the best options currently available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to do a straight functional test of your web page or are you looking to narrow your tests specifically to the JavaScript in ExtJS?

If it's the former (functional at the UI level), then WatiN/Watir/Webdriver ought to work for you. (If they're not working then I'd love to get more details around specific issues you're running in to.)

If it's the latter then you might investigate Jasmine which gives a lot of interesting capabilities around unit testing your JavaScript at the UI layer.

(If it's functional testing, you might also check out [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/) for functional automation. I'm the Evangelist for that tool, so I'm a bit biased...)

Comment: Thanks. I have already downloaded some free web testing framework from Telerik, i wonder if you meant the same thing. I am not so familiar with ExtJS and how it is built, and so i wonder if WatiN or similar frameworks can handle it properly.

Comment: BTE Could you elaborate on the differences between functional and JS related testing? what tests belong to the latter for example?

Comment: Functional testing would be driving the browser around to do things like validating you're able to put items in your shopping cart. WatiN/Watir/Selenium and Test Studio are all great at that. (The free framework you got from Telerik is the underpinnings for the full-blown standalone version of Test Studio. JavaScript testing via Jasmine would let you write unit/integration tests for your in-browser JavaScript. This would let you do things like test validations or other logic/behavior you have in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at using Siesta, it's a unit testing and functional testing tool designed to help you test Ext JS and Sencha Touch (and it's also used by Sencha internally to test Ext JS itself). Since Siesta knows a lot about Ext JS you can write expressive tests using Component Query instead of CSS and get much more robust test compared to simpler tools described in other answers in this thread. Here's a sample test script in plain JS:

```
t.chain(
    { click : ">>textfield[name=user]" },

    { type : "Mike[TAB]Password" },

    { click : ">>button[name=loginbutton]" }
);
```

DISCLAIMER: I work for the company that created it.

http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/extjs.html).

Version 5.0 fully supports ExtJS testing. ExtJS UI widgets are first class citizen in RIATest. This means that unlike other HTML testing tools you do not need to write tests that manipulate the HTML DOM elements. The tests in RIATest operate in terms of ExtJS UI widgets.

**Examples of RIATest scripts that work with ExtJS widgets:**

The following clicks on an ExtJS button with label "Next Page":

```
ExtButton("Next Page")=>click();
```

And the following does drag-n-drop of a row from one ExtJS tree to another:

```
ExtRow("Controller.js")=>dragAndDropTo(ExtTreePanel("#tree2")->ExtRow("Custom Ext JS"));
```

And this collapses the header of an ExtJS box:

```
ExtBox("Feeds")->ExtHeader("FeedsВ")->ExtCollapser()=>click();
```

*(All sample code above is from real test scripts that run on ExtJS sample applications).*

RIATest also knows when to automatically wait for ExtJS AJAX to finish, so if your UI does dynamic content downloading the tests will auto-magically wait until data is received from server.

(Disclaimer: I am a RIATest team member).

Answer (score 1):

Sahi is an automation and testing tool I have recently come around as I am in a similar search as you...  Selenium hasnt worked for me (as it hasnt for many around the web... havent found anything to make it work... dynamic IDs and other Ext related particularities mess with it apparently)...

take a look at sahi maybe it will be useful... www.sahi.co.in (I have no relation, I discovered it recently and found it useful).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do Functional Testing.   [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a good choice.  It has API implementations in a slew of languages (Java, Ruby, Python) and it uses [Webdriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) under the covers.

Comment: We are already using WatiN, not sure how different it is from Selenium. The main point is we need to easily support ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex can handle Ext-Js as well, although turning it into first class citizens will require some custom coding. The secret in general is to avoid using id's for object recognition, as they change around and use innertext property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally found using xpath with extjs flaky in places.

You're better off (in Java) writing a method which uses a JavaScript component query to pull out the element id. (if it has one)